# How to create an external table for a google cloud storage and query the externally partitioned data?

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-storage, external-tables

I am trying to query the externally partitioned data with the reference of this BigQuery [doc](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/hive-partitioned-queries-gcs)

**Google Cloud Storage:** (csv data contains string value only)

```
gs://project/myfolder/count=1000/file_1k.csv
gs://project/myfolder/count=10000/file_10k.csv
gs://project/myfolder/count=100000/file_100k.csv
```

**Source URI prefix:** gs://project/myfolder

But I am getting the following error while querying the table,

```
Error while reading table: project.dataset.partition_table, 
error message: Cannot query hive partitioned data for table project.dataset.partition_table without any associated files.
```

**Query:**

```
SELECT * FROM `project.dataset.partition_table` where count=1000 order by rand() LIMIT 100;
```

Refer the screenshot,
[image]

Any inputs here really appreciated.

Comment: Can you share your query?

Comment: @rmesteves Question updated with query.

Comment: I tried reproducing the issue but it worked fine for me. The error seems to be indicating that your partition doesn't has a file associated. Did you checked all your partition's files?

Comment: Kindly provide the steps to create external table in BigQuery.

Comment: @rmesteves How can I check the partition has a file associated?

Comment: I followed the same documentation you provided in your post. Can you explain me the steps you took? Because I couldnt reproduce the same issue

Comment: but am getting the same error..

Comment: Can you add some screenshots explaining the steps you took to create the table?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209529/discussion-between-sst-and-rmesteves).

Comment: Try putting gs://project/myfolder/* instead of gs://project/myfolder in your "Select file from GCS bucket" field. Please let me know it works

Comment: May I post it as an answer?

Comment: @rmesteves Yes, you can.

Comment: Posted. Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that the engine can't find the files related to the partitions.
In your case, its because when you created the table you referenced a folder in `GCS` but not it's files.

To solve your problem, you should use a wildcard and your path would be `gs://project/myfolder/*` instead of `gs://project/myfolder`

I hope it helps